# Coffeescript, calling a function from inside a click event

Tags: function, coffeescript, scope

I have this bit of Coffeescript

```
d3Graph: =>

  refreshData: ->
    console.log "refresh data called"

  someButton.click ->
    refreshData()
```

When I click "someButton" I receive an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: refreshData is not defined
```

Anyone see my error?

Comment: _Always_ always [checkout the compiled output](http://coffeescript.org/#try:d3Graph%3A%20%3D%3E%0A%0A%20%20refreshData%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22refresh%20data%20called%22%0A%0A%20%20someButton.click%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20refreshData()). When you do that, the problem usually becomes somewhat obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `refreshData =` instead of `refreshData:` here.

```
d3Graph: =>

  refreshData = ->
    console.log "refresh data called"

  someButton.click ->
    refreshData()
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to provide more complete code.

If you run into problems like this, it's always helpful to see what the output JavaScript is.

For instance, in this case, your original code outputs:

```
var _this = this;

({
  d3Graph: function() {
    ({
      refreshData: function() {
        return console.log("refresh data called");
      }
    });
    return someButton.click(function() {
      return refreshData();
    });
  }
});
```

So it should be apparent that there is no variable/function called `refreshData`!

Answer (score 0):

Jamie Wong explains it correctly. I was just wondering if you were trying to use d3Graph as a class:

```
class d3Graph

  @refreshData: ->
    console.log "refresh data called"

someButton.click ->
  d3Graph.refreshData()
```

or when the graph is an instance:

```
class d3Graph

  refreshData: ->
    console.log "refresh data called"

graph = new d3Graph()

someButton.click ->
  graph.refreshData()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I'm not creating a class but thanks for the suggestion.  I'm still learning coffeescript (obviously), I'm sure I'll make a class sometime soon and use what you suggested.  :)